# How to compile CGAL code into a shared library?

Tags: linux, cmake, shared-libraries, cgal, .so

This is a pretty rookie question, but unfortunately I'm not really familiar with cmake or CGAL. I just can't figure out how to configure cmake to generate a shared library from my source code. I looked through some docs and some pages on github, but I don't seem to get anywehere.
I would be really grateful if someone could point me to some documentation, or provide an example CMakeLists.txt or something (to be honest I'm completely lost here).

I need the .so-s for a python binding for some functionality of the 2D arrangements package.

Comment: Please post the *specific* steps or tutorials you have tried so far. For example, have you tried the examples on the [CGAL Github](https://github.com/CGAL/cgal/wiki/How-to-use-CGAL-with-CMake-or-your-own-build-system)? When you say Python bindings, are you referring to something like SWIG? Instructions for this are also right on their Github [here](https://github.com/cgal/cgal-swig-bindings/wiki/Installation).

Comment: Thank you very much! I looked on github and found [this](https://github.com/CGAL/cgal/wiki/Libraries). I really dont know how I could have missed this out.

Comment: I only scratched the surface of the docs, next time I'll make sure to do proper research

Comment: Glad this helped! For completeness, I posted an answer with some links.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The CGAL [Manual](https://doc.cgal.org/latest/Manual/installation.html) has copious information you can use to get you started. Here you'll find information for building/installing CGAL itself.

If you already have CGAL built/installed on your system, there are some examples to show how to use it in your own CMake project. Check out their Github [wiki](https://github.com/CGAL/cgal/wiki/How-to-use-CGAL-with-CMake-or-your-own-build-system), or for even more info, [Sections 14](https://doc.cgal.org/latest/Manual/installation.html#title42) and 15 of their Installation Manual.

You mention python bindings, so if your looking to use something like SWIG, I suggest taking a look [here](https://github.com/cgal/cgal-swig-bindings/wiki/Installation).